# Find time gaps between multiple dates - Kettle

Tags: mysql, date, pentaho, kettle

I need to find gaps between multiple start-end date rows(it can be up to 4 rows per PK). I have an input of combinations PK - start date - end date, and I need to somehow check if I have any gaps between this dates. For example:

```
PK          Start                    End
1        2016-01-01 00:00      2016-01-01 11:00
1        2016-01-01 10:00      2016-01-01 21:00
1        2016-01-01 13:00      2016-01-01 16:00
1        2016-01-01 18:00      2016-01-01 21:00
2        2016-01-01 11:00      2016-01-01 12:00
2 .......................
```

I tried using the analytical step in Kettle to get the previous row's end date, and then compare it with the start date of current row, but this won't do the trick because the times can be overlapping, or as in the example if i compare row 3 and row 4 it would report an error, even tough the time is covered by row 2. So i need a solution that would compare all the rows with the same PK, and check if there is a time gap between them. I tried to create some Kettle transformation/job or a MySQL query, but i can't seem to get this right. Any ideas/suggestions?

EDIT:
Now I'm trying with something like this(simplified):

```
SELECT t.id, t.start,t.end, max(t2.end)
FROM t, t  t2
WHERE t2.start <= t.start
GROUP BY t.pk
```

But the problem now is that I'm getting just one row back per PK, with Max. I would need the 'running max'. The idea behind this it to get the Max end date until now for every PK group, and compare it with the Start date(if the result is >= 0, there is no gap). So with the example before it would be:

```
PK          Start                    End                 MAX
1        2016-01-01 00:00      2016-01-01 11:00      2016-01-01 11:00
1        2016-01-01 10:00      2016-01-01 21:00      2016-01-01 21:00
1        2016-01-01 13:00      2016-01-01 16:00      2016-01-01 21:00
1        2016-01-01 18:00      2016-01-01 21:00      2016-01-01 21:00
2        2016-01-01 11:00      2016-01-01 12:00      2016-01-01 12:00
2 .......................
```

Again, any idea how to get this to function properly?
Thanks.

Comment: Given the data set above, what should the desired result look like?

Comment: I just need to know which PK has a gap. So, it can return a PK, it can return the whole row, doesn't matter.

Comment: In the above example, which PK has a gap?

Comment: Ok,maybe not the best example, this example was showing that by using just values from the previous row I would get the 'gap' even though there is no gap.(row 3 and row 4 - a gap, even tough the time is covered by row 2.). I will edit the question with the progress made, maybe then some idea will show up.

Comment: Have a look at some recent, successfully answered questions. One common theme is the provision of a representative data set (often as a set of create and insert statements and/or an sqlfiddle) together with a desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you a check using having for the max .. min delta e the sum (total) of the parts ..

```
 select pk, max(end) - min(start) as delta , sum(start - end) as tot
 from my_table
 goup by pk
 having delta - tot > 0
```

eventually you can manage a bit of tolerance .. too

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I don't see this working. Could you explain a bit?

Comment: There was an errror  . i have udapte the answer .. the idea is check if the absolute diff (delta) is > of  sum of single diff then there is gaps between the dates otherwise all the time period is continuosly covered .

Comment: Sounds good :) I'm implementing it now, so far it looks good :) Thanks!

Comment: If i got this correct, then I need to use ABS(sum(start-end) as tot. Correct me if i'm wrong. Thanks one more time :)

Comment: you can use it but it should not be necessary as the end time should always be larger than the start time, and then the differences should both always be positive.

Comment: So close...but now I found an example where it's not working...
01:00 - 10:00
11:00 - 21:00
18:00 - 21:00
So delta is 20, and sum is 22...

Comment: You have overlapping period .. related to the same evaluation?

Comment: Yes, there are overlapping periods in the same day for the same PK. Any suggestions?

Comment: With relation query this  is not possible ! .. You can explore (but is really diifcult) with procedural code ..